# Create a Column for a Double in ms-Access via SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to create columns within my ms-access table using SQL. I want to put `double`s from my vb.net software into the column with several decimal places. I am unsure of the correct column type to use to enable access to receive the decimal places. As below I have tried `long` but this seems to be long integer rather than a long number. From Microsoft.com it would appear that my options are the following:

> `CHAR [( {size} )] | CHARACTER [( {size} )] | LONGCHAR | SHORT | INT | INTEGER | LONG | OBJECT [NOT NULL] [TEMPORARY] [LOCALIZABLE] [HOLD]`.

My current code is below, the sub runs a functions to access the database.

```
    Public Sub AddColumnsToDatabase(ByVal Parameter)

    Dim scaleCounter
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim ColumnString As String
For scaleCounter = 2 To 2
        DatabaseSelector(scaleCounter)
        TableName = DataLocations(1, scaleCounter)

        cnnOLEDB = New OleDbConnection
        cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DataDirectoryName & DatabaseFileName
        cnnOLEDB.Open()

        cmdOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB

        ColumnString = "PAR" & Format(Parameter, "0000")
        DatabaseConnectioninsert("ALTER TABLE " & TableName & " ADD " & ColumnString & " Long", "Non-Query")

        cnnOLEDB.Close()
        rdrOLEDB.Close()
end sub

 Public Function DatabaseConnectioninsert(ByVal Query As String, ByVal Task As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Err

    cmdOLEDB.CommandText = Query

    Select Case Task
        Case "Read Recordset"
            rdrOLEDB = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteReader()
            DatabaseConnectioninsert = "Read Recordset"
        Case "Read Scalar"
            DatabaseConnectioninsert = cmdOLEDB.ExecuteScalar
        Case "Non-Query"
            cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery()
            DatabaseConnectioninsert = "Non-Query"
    End Select


    Exit Function
Err:
    DatabaseConnectioninsert = "Error"


End Function
```

An example SQL query is `Query = "ALTER TABLE tabDataHourly ADD PAR0005 Long"`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Be aware that you must be careful with comparisons using double: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/double-vs-decimal-t3398899.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DOUBLE` for the field type.

```
ALTER TABLE tabDataHourly ADD COLUMN PAR0005 DOUBLE;
```

You can find more information about Access DDL field types here: [Field type reference - names and values for DDL, DAO, and ADOX](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html)